# How to remove filter criteria and display data on focus of a Text Input field when using Jquery Autocomplete feature

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a program which is responsible to display autosuggestions .

When i keep the focus inside the tags input field , it should display all the available data present inside the source , (i don't need any filter criteria )

**On focus of the  text input field it should display all the data**

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n30bku6v/1/

```
$(document).on('focus', '#tags', function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Could you please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you should bring your `autocomplete` initialization out of `onFocus` callback, so it won't initialize on each focus event.

To achieve your desired behavior, you could use [`minLength`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) property and [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        minLength: 0
    });
    
    $(document).on('focus', '#tags', function() {
        $("#tags").autocomplete("search","");
    });    
});
```

Using `minLength` we say to autocomplete to work even when there is no query, and `search` method is used to trigger autocomplete with empty query.

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/n30bku6v/3/)

Comment: When i am implementing this , i am getting Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'search'

Comment: Are you initializing `autocomplete` when DOM is ready? See updated code and jsfiddle in my answer.